# How do I use the CoffeeScript existential operator to check some object properties for undefined?

Tags: coffeescript, existential-operator

I would like to use the CoffeeScript existential operator to check some object properties for undefined. However, I encountered a little problem.

Code like this:

```
console.log test if test?
```

Compiles to:

```
if (typeof test !== "undefined" && test !== null) console.log(test);
```

Which is the behavior I would like to see. However, when I try using it against object properties, like this:

```
console.log test.test if test.test?
```

I get something like that:

```
if (test.test != null) console.log(test.test);
```

Which desn't look like a check against undefined at all. The only way I could have achieved the same (1:1) behavior as using it for objects was by using a larger check:

```
console.log test.test if typeof test.test != "undefined" and test.test != null
```

The question is - am I doing something wrong? Or is the compiled code what is enough to check for existence of a property (a null check with type conversion)?

Comment: exact duplicate of [coffeescript not null or undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010245/coffeescript-not-null-or-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @Bergi, this question was asked four years ago, the other - two years ago. Isn't the other one the duplicate? :)

Comment: Right, I just felt the other one had the better answer. I guess they should be merged.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is a common point of confusion with the existential operator: Sometimes

```
x?
```

compiles to

```
typeof test !== "undefined" && test !== null
```

and other times it just compiles to

```
x != null
```

*The two are equivalent,* because `x != null` will be `false` when `x` is either `null` or `undefined`. So `x != null` is a more compact way of expressing `(x !== undefined && x !== null)`. The reason the `typeof` compilation occurs is that the compiler thinks `x` may not have been defined at all, in which case doing an equality test would trigger `ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

In your particular case, `test.test` may have the value `undefined`, but you can't get a `ReferenceError` by referring to an undefined property on an existing object, so the compiler opts for the shorter output.

Comment: Thanks!  Succinct and informative for those of us who have avoided Javascript prior to Coffeescript  :)

Answer (score 20):

This JavaScript:

```
a.foo != null
```

actually does check if the `foo` property of `a` is neither `undefined` nor `null`. Note that `a.foo?` is translated to JavaScript that uses `!= null` rather than `!== null`. The conversions that `!=` does means that both of these are true:

```
null == null
undefined == null
```

A plain `a?` becomes this JavaScript:

```
typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null
```

because there are three conditions to check:

1. Is there an `a` in scope anywhere?
2. Does `a` have a value of `undefined`?
3. Does `a` have a value of `null`?

The first condition is important as just saying `a != null` will trigger a ReferenceError if there is no `a` in scope but saying `typeof a === 'undefined'` won't. The `typeof` check also takes care of the `a === undefined` condition in **2**. Then we can finish it off with a strict `a !== null` test as that takes care of **3** without the performance penalty of an unnecessary `!=` (note: `!=` and `==` are slower than `!==` and `===` due to the implicit conversions).

A little reading on what `!=` and `!==` do might be fruitful:

> [**MDN: Comparison Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

---

As far as your comment on the deleted answer is concerned, `if(a.foo)` is perfectly valid syntax **if** you complete the `if` statement:

```
if(a.foo)
    do_interesting_things()
# or
do_interesting_things() if(a.foo)
```

However, `if(a.foo)` and `if(a.foo?)` differ in how they handle `0`, `false`, and `''`.

Comment: first result on google; but actually !== returns an error. could we clarify ?

Comment: @Ben: Not sure what you mean, what use of `!==` returns an error and what is the error?

Comment: coffeecript-rails (coffeescript 2.2.0), "SyntaxError: [stdin]:37:38: unexpected ="; a nice 500 error, it just does not compile with a third character in the comparison elements

Comment: @Ben You're trying to use `!==` in CoffeeScript? That's a JavaScript operator, CoffeeScript's `!=` is converted to `!==` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Wild guess; have you tried `console.log test.test if test?.test?`?

Just tested it with `coffee -p -e 'console.log test.test if test?.test?'`, which compiles to:

> (function() {
>
> if ((typeof test !== "undefined" && test !== null ? test.test : void
>   0) != null) {
>       console.log(test.test);   }
>
> }).call(this);

Comment: This is really useful, and exactly why I ended up at this question, so vote up for that! Makes the if statements a lot more succinct.