# CoffeeScript Existential Operator and this

Tags: coffeescript

I noticed something a little odd with the CoffeeScript compilier and was wondering if this was correct behavior or not. If it is correct I'm curious why there is a difference..

Given the following CoffeeScript:

```
if @myVar?
  alert myVar
```

I was expecting it to compile to JavaScript like this:

```
if (typeof this.myVar !== "undefined" && this.myVar !== null) {
  alert(myVar);
}
```

But instead what the CoffeeScript compiler outputs is this:

```
if (this.myVar != null) {
  alert(myVar);
}
```

If I don't reference this (or any other parent object), the CoffeeScript compiles as I would expect.

Is this the correct behavior? If so, why does it work different when using this?

Edit:

To add a little more clarification. This doesn't happen with only this, but any other properties of objects. For instance, if I were replace the above CoffeeScript with what's below it still would compile with only "!= null"...

```
if myVar.myProp?
  alert myVar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Existential operator and object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990117/existential-operator-and-object-properties)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the case of:

```
myVar = 10
if myVar?
  alert myVar
```

Coffeescript compiler is able to see that `myVar` is really defined in the first line, so it can omit `typeof myVar !== "undefined"` check.

```
if (myVar !== null) {
  alert(myVar);
}
```

But in this case:

```
if myVar?
  alert myVar
```

compiler can't guarantee that `myVar` is actually defined, so extra check is required:

```
if (typeof myVar !== "undefined" && myVar !== null) {
  alert(myVar);
}
```

So, the answer is: Coffeescript compiler tries to be smart to produce efficient code.

**EDIT**
The way Coffeescript deals with properties is also correct: `this.prop` will return `undefined` if property is not defined. `!=` will convert it to null. That is why we don't need additional check.
In few words:

- accessing undefined variable throws exception -- need to check `typeof`
- accessing undefined property returns `undefined` -- just `!=` is enough

Comment: I understand that. My question had more to do with checking existence of properties on objects.. this.var, or that.var.property.. etc.. it omits the undefined check and only does a != null instead of !== null...

Comment: I understand now. I have to chalk this up to my lack of understanding of the CoffeeScript compiler :) I really didn't know it was smart enough to make these "decisions". That's really good to know, though. Thank you very much for the insight!