# node.js - strange behavior of coffeescript compiler

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I noticed an unexplainable behavior of the coffeescript compiler for me :)

For example:

```
getImage: (req, res) =>
    realty_id = req.query.id

    if (realty_id?)
```

Result

```
ImageController.prototype.getImage = function(req, res) {
    var realty_id,
        _this = this;
      realty_id = req.query.id;
      if ((realty_id != null)
```

But actually the last line should be: if ((typeof realty_id !== "undefined" && realty_id !== null))

When I comment out "realty_id = req.query.id" it works well. Has anyone a explanation for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992620/coffeescript-existential-operator-and-this

Answer (score 3):

**tldr;** `typeof x !== "undefined"` is not needed with *local* JavaScript variables.

The SO question [CoffeeScript Existential Operator and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992620/coffeescript-existential-operator-and-this) has information on *why* CoffeeScript will make this optimization.

Now, to see why it is a *valid* code generation in the presented case:

```
-> x         x != null   typeof x !== "undefined" && x !== null
----------   ---------   -------------------------------------
ANY_TRUE     true        true
0            true        true
null         false       false
undefined    false       false
```

So, according to the logic tables, they are semantically equivalent. It is the "non strict" nature of the `==` operator that determines the - perhaps surprising - result of this comparison: SO questions on the topic abound.

However, here is the important difference of when/why `typeof x !== "undefined"` is sometimes used: it will *not* result in a `ReferenceError`. If `x` is known to be a *local variable* then there is no such consideration and the shorter (`!=`) JavaScript expression can be safely used.

In the case when the assignment in CoffeeScript is commented out, there is *no* local variable/binding with the name `reality_id` - note that the `var` statement is also different - and CoffeeScript inserts the additional guard as appropriate.