# Checking if a variable exists in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know there are two methods to determine if a variable exists and not null(false, empty) in javascript:

1) `if ( typeof variableName !== 'undefined' && variableName )`

2) `if ( window.variableName )`

which one is more preferred and why?

Comment: Why `window.variableName`? If the variable is local, that will turn up undefined even if the variable is defined.

Comment: Also, being "not null" is orthogonal to whether the value of the variable is `false`.

Comment: Coffeescript has its own operator for this problem and the JS code generated from it is quite interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992620/coffeescript-existential-operator-and-this

Comment: The titel contains a different question than the text.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

A variable is *declared* if accessing the variable name will not produce a `ReferenceError`. The expression `typeof variableName !== 'undefined'` will be  `false` in only one of two cases:

- the variable is not declared (i.e., there is no `var variableName` in scope), *or*
- the variable is declared and its value is `undefined` (i.e., the variable's *value* is *not defined*)

Otherwise, the comparison evaluates to `true`.

If you really want to test if a variable is declared or not, you'll need to `catch` any `ReferenceError` produced by attempts to reference it:

```
var barIsDeclared = true; 
try{ bar; }
catch(e) {
    if(e.name == "ReferenceError") {
        barIsDeclared = false;
    }
}
```

If you merely want to test if a declared variable's value is neither `undefined` nor `null`, you can simply test for it:

```
if (variableName !== undefined && variableName !== null) { ... }
```

Or equivalently, with a non-strict equality check against `null`:

```
if (variableName != null) { ... }
```

Both your second example and your right-hand expression in the `&&` operation tests if the value is "falsey", i.e., if it coerces to `false` in a boolean context. Such values include `null`, `false`, `0`, and the empty string, not all of which you may want to discard.

Comment: What's the difference between "a variable is not declared" and " a variable is undeclared"?

Comment: @TomasZubiri There is no difference; I've just now changed "test if a variable is undeclared" to "test if a variable is declared or not". I hope that's more clear.

Comment: Oh I get it, because the other test would return false if the variable was declared but the value was undefined.

Comment: Is it really necessary to check the error name ? Just curious that what could be errors other than ReferenceError ?

Comment: @Sid The only one I was thinking of was if `bar` has an underlying getter that throws an error: `Object.defineProperty(window, "bar", { get: function (){ throw "something"; })`

Comment: Thanks @apsillers. That makes sense.

Answer (score 20):

It is important to note that 'undefined' is a perfectly valid value for a variable to hold.  If you want to check if the variable exists at all,

```
if (window.variableName)
```

is a more complete check, since it is verifying that the variable has actually been defined.  However, this is only useful if the variable is guaranteed to be an object! In addition, as others have pointed out, this could also return false if the value of variableName is false, 0, '', or null.

That said, that is usually not enough for our everyday purposes, since we often don't want to have an undefined value.  As such, you should first check to see that the variable is defined, and then assert that it is not undefined using the typeof operator which, as Adam has pointed out, will not return undefined unless the variable truly is undefined.

```
if ( variableName  && typeof variableName !== 'undefined' )
```

Comment: While undefined might by a valid value for a variable to hold, checking typeof will not return undefined unless the variable truly is undefined.

Comment: `if (window.variableName)` has a major flaw, in that it will return a false negative for anything that **has** been defined, but is falsy.  So any variables that are `false`, `0`, `''`, `null`, or others will give the wrong result.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent points.  It further helped to solidify my own understanding and I've updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: The `window.` helped me get rid of an referenceexception here. Thanks.

Comment: `if ( variableName  && typeof variableName !== 'undefined' )` is reversed...it should be `if ( typeof variableName !== 'undefined' && variableName  )` .  My page was crashing until I flipped these two conditions.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to check if a variable (say v) has been defined and is not null:

```
if (typeof v !== 'undefined' && v !== null) {
    // Do some operation  
}
```

If you want to check for all falsy values such as: `undefined`, `null`, `''`, `0`, `false`:

```
if (v) {
   // Do some operation
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm writing an answer only because I do not have enough reputations to comment the accepted answer from **apsillers**.
I agree with his answer, but

> If you really want to test if a variable is undeclared, you'll need to
>   catch the ReferenceError ...

is not the only way. One can do just:

```
this.hasOwnProperty("bar")
```

to check if there is a variable **bar** declared in the current context.
(I'm not sure, but calling the **hasOwnProperty** could also be more fast/effective than raising an exception)
This works only for the current context (not for the whole current scope).

Comment: Not working with the non-global variables e.g. variables within the function.

Comment: What do you mean by that? (did you read the last sentence of my answer, i.e. context vs. scope ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( typeof variableName !== 'undefined' && variableName )
//// could throw an error if var doesnt exist at all

if ( window.variableName )
//// could be true if var == 0

////further on it depends on what is stored into that var
// if you expect an object to be stored in that var maybe
if ( !!window.variableName )
//could be the right way

best way => see what works for your case
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this shorter and much better:

```
    if(varName !== (undefined || null)) { //do something }
```

Comment: This will not work. `(undefined || null)` evaluates to `null`.  This statement is basically just `if (varName !== null)`.

Answer (score -1):

`if (variable)` can be used if variable is guaranteed to be an object, or if false, 0, etc. are considered "default" values (hence equivalent to undefined or null).

`typeof variable == 'undefined'` can be used in cases where a specified null has a distinct meaning to an uninitialised variable or property. This check will not throw and error is variable is not declared.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do
`if(variableName){console.log("Variable exist")}`