# How to check if a variable is undefined versus it is undeclared in javascript?

Tags: javascript, undefined, detection, undeclared-identifier

I know that to find if a variable is undeclared in javascript, I can use `if (typeof variable === 'undefined')`. If I declare a variable as undefined (`var variable = undefined`), the if statement still returns true. Is it possible, in JavaScript, to find the difference between undeclared variables and variables with a value of undefined? I know that they are similar, but doing `const variable = undefined` and then `variable = "something else"` will throw an error, so they must be different.

```js
const variable = undefined

if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
  console.log('"variable" is undefined')
}

if (typeof undeclaredVariable === 'undefined') {
  console.log('"undeclaredVariable" is undefined')
}
```

I wouldn't like to use a try catch block because I want to be able to assign another constant based on this. I would like a solution like this: `const isVariableDeclared = variable === undeclared`, except `undeclared` does not exist in javascript. I know I can use let with a try catch block but am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking. But what you call `undefinedVariable` in your example is better described as *undeclared* rather than *undefined*. You can tell these, in a sense, because any reference to them *except* for the `typeof` operator will throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: it is not possible. it exists only one `undefined`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unset a JavaScript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Use a 'try catch' to reference the variable. I think that's the only way to check if a variable is declared.

Comment: There isn't one, except that if you use a variable you haven't declared in anything other than an assignment expression or the typeof operator your code won't run and you will get a ReferenceError.

Comment: [Using typeof vs === to check undeclared variable produces different result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31671887)

Comment: From the example you shown, did you mean undeclared?

Comment: @Ava I mean undeclared and have edited the question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik No, I am asking what is the difference instead of how to change a variable to undeclared.

Comment: @nthnchu ... regarding the last sentence within the OP's explanation ... *"... but doing const variable = undefined and then variable = "something else" will throw an error, so they must be different"* ..  **one can not reassign a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) in JavaScript .**

Comment: @PeterSeliger I know, I was trying to show that it wasn't the same as undeclared.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I already knew how to delete a variable. Is there something I don't understand about the other question that relates it to this one?

Comment: Use an object to define it and check if the object has the own property inside, maybe that's the only way if try catch does not satisfy you

Comment: I think I see what you're saying (`window.hasOwnProperty("variableName")`). That only works for variables declared with var, however. You should promote that to an answer, though.

Comment: @nthnchu Not quite. This may be a purely theoretical question; but in real code, you should _always_ know if a variable is declared or not. It should never be unknown; it should never be a surprise whether a variable is declared or not. The suggestion was to use an object instead, i.e. `const object = {};` and set properties on it, e.g. `object.var1 = "something";` Checking whether `var1` and `var2` exist looks like this: `object.hasOwnProperty("var1")` and `object.hasOwnProperty("var2")`, which yield `true` and `false`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in the time of writing... No, it does not seem that you can do something like this:

```
var a = undeclared(var) ? 'undeclared' : 'undefined'
```

The reason is that you cannot pass an undeclared variable to a function; It raises an error, even in non-strict mode.

The best we can do, is this:

```js
var barIsDeclared = true;

try { bar; }
catch (e) {
  if (e.name == "ReferenceError") {
    barIsDeclared = false;
  }
}

console.log(barIsDeclared);
```

### Why?

> **Undefined**: It occurs when a variable has been declared but has not
> been assigned with any value. Undefined is not a keyword.
>
> **Undeclared**: It occurs when we try to access any variable that is not
> initialized or declared earlier using var or const keyword. If we use
> ‘typeof’ operator to get the value of an undeclared variable, we will
> face the runtime error with return value as “undefined”. The scope of
> the undeclared variables is always global.

**For example:**

- **Undefined:**

```
var a;
undefined
console.log(a) // Success!
```

- **Undeclared:**

```
console.log(myVariable) // ReferenceError: myVariable is not defined
```

When we try to log an `undeclared` variable, it raises an error. Trying to log an `undefined` variable does not. We make a `try catch` to check for just that.

### `'use strict'`

Worth mentioning that adding `'use strict'` in your code verifies that no undeclared variable is present, and raises an error if one is present.

```
function define() {
 //'use strict' verifies that no undeclared variable is present in our code     
 'use strict';     
 x = "Defined";  
}

define();

ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

### Further reading:

- [Checking if a variable exists in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719348/13331155)
- [What are undeclared and undefined variables in JavaScript?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-undeclared-and-undefined-variables-in-javascript)
- [JS Interview Question: What’s the difference between a variable that is: null, undefined or undeclared?](https://medium.com/@rlynjb/js-interview-question-what-s-the-difference-between-a-variable-that-is-null-undefined-or-bf7233cef1c2)
- [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized)
- [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: Good answer, and while it's not exactly an ideal solution it helped me come up with one that worked for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

As others already did point to, the OP might want to distinguish between declared but undefined references and undeclared reference names ...

```js
let declaredButUnassignedAndStrictlyEqualToUndefinedValue;
const declaredAndHavingAssignedTheUndefinedValue = undefined;

// There is no way of telling the above two (un/)assignements appart.

console.log(
  '(declaredButUnassignedAndStrictlyEqualToUndefinedValue === declaredAndHavingAssignedTheUndefinedValue) ?',
  (declaredButUnassignedAndStrictlyEqualToUndefinedValue === declaredAndHavingAssignedTheUndefinedValue)
);


// the `typeof` operator is of no help
// if it comes to distinguish between
// declared but undefined references
// and undeclared reference names ...

console.log(
  'typeof notDeclaredWithinScope :', typeof notDeclaredWithinScope
);

// ... just a try catch can do that.

try {
  notDeclaredWithinScope;
} catch (err) {
  // console.log(err.message);

  console.log('`notDeclaredWithinScope` does not exist within this scope.')
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm looking for another way different than try catch. Good answer though, and I'll accept it if no one has another way.

Comment: @nthnchu ... As long as one is dealing with variable names as described by the original Q there will hardly be another approach. There are other, more elegant, solutions if one was allowed to only focus on property names and context.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what your saying. There is no defined way to get the exact answer but there is a way to find whether it is defined or not. It is possible only if it referenced somewhere.

Eg:
// Lets think x is not defined

x.substring(1);

Output:
ReferenceError: "x" is not defined

So if you use try catch block method, with the help of catch error message you can identify whether it is defined or not!