# Coffee Existential Operator different compliations

Tags: coffeescript

Similar to this topic:
[CoffeeScript Existential Operator and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992620/coffeescript-existential-operator-and-this)

The coffeescript, I'm having a problem using the elvis operator:

```
foo = -> 
  y = foo()
  console.log 'y is null' unless y?
  console.log 'x is null' unless x?
```

Compiles to:

```
var foo, y;
foo = function() {};
y = foo();
if (y == null) {
  console.log('y is null');
}
if (typeof x === "undefined" || x === null) {
  console.log('x is null');
}
```

Output:

```
y is null
x is null
```

So the problem is that since y is assigned earlier that coffee takes the shortcut and assumes that y cannot be undefined.  However, it is valid to return undefined from a function.

Is there a "safer" way to check that y is also not undefined?

**UPDATED**
Clarified Examples and Explanation:

From the comments, in the first if statement (y == null) is using double equal instead of ( x === null) triple equal, as in the second if statement.  Clever.

Comment: i think you're conflating three different things here: (1) does `y` exist / has it been declared? (2) does `y` have the value `undefined`? (3) does `y` have the value `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` operator always checks if the value is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

`y == null` is absolutely correct way to check that the value of `y` is either `null` or `undefined` in JavaScript.

For example, the following CofeeScript code checks only for `null` values:

```
do_something() if y is null
```

which compiles to

```
if (y === null) do_something();
```

So, while `y?` (`y == null` in JS) checks for both `null` and `undefined`, `y isnt null` (`y !== null` in JS) checks only for `null`.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990117/how-do-i-use-the-coffeescript-existential-operator-to-check-some-object-properti/9995425#9995425) for more detailed information.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more info about equality checks in JavaScript.

Comment: "? operator always checks if the value is neither null nor undefined."  Thats what I thought, but in my example above it doesn't check for undefined only null.  So y gets assigned to undefined, then fails the check against null.

Comment: @bryce look closely to your example, it checks for `y == null` which is actually `null` or `undefined`. Real `null` check is `y === null` and not `y == null`, see my example above.

Comment: @bryce See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more info about equality checks in JavaScript.