# Why is the difference between the compiled javascript while using question mark operator

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

**Without `@`**

```
alert("Even Number") if even?
```

**Corresponding Javascript**

```
if (typeof even !== "undefined" && even !== null) {
  alert("Even Number");
}
```

**With `@`**

```
alert("Even Number") if @even?
```

**Corresponding Javascript**

```
if (this.even != null) {
  alert("Even Number");
}
```

I want the check for `undefined` when I use the `this` operator along with `?` Am I missing something?

Comment: `if (this.even != null || this.even != '') {
  alert("Even Number");
}`

Doesn't this work?

Comment: `this.even?` should do.

Comment: I can do it manually, but I just want to know why is this difference between the compiled javascript

Comment: @elclanrs this.even? evaluates to this.even != null

Comment: This question has been asked many times (it's probably not a very search engine friendly question). Should we start marking them as duplicates? This is the duplicate with most votes i found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9990117/581845

Comment: @epidemian Agreed, you can mark this as duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to an undefined variable, JS throws a ReferenceError. If you refer to an undefined object member, you get `undefined`. That is why you don't need to check if the object member exists before testing it against `null`.

Consider:

```
var obj = {};

if( obj.foo != null ) {   // this is fine because `obj.foo` is `undefined`
   // ...
}

if( foo != null ) {       // ReferenceError, script execution halts
   // ...
}
```

In other words there is no need to safeguard against the object member not existing so CoffeeScript doesn't do it. You have to do it manually if you want to specifically check for the member not existing at all.

Comment: a = {test: (-> @b?)} ; a.test() would return false while I want it to return true, I can do manual check to undefined in coffeescript but that is what the "?" is supposed to do which it is failing

Comment: But in that case you're testing for "truthy or undefined". It's clearly a special case. I'm not really sure what your point is: `a = {test: (-> b?)} ; a.test()` would also return false.

Answer (score 4):

Coffeecript is just being smart. The trick here is that comparing to `null` with `!=` checks for `undefined` as well. You don't need to check for existence of the variable because `this` is already an object, and you can check if a property exists by just using a regular lookup like `if (this.prop)`, but that would fail if the value is falsy (false, empty string, etc...), that's why you need the check for `undefined` or `null` which would be written like:

```
if (this.prop !== undefined && this.prop !== null)
```

But taking advantage of type casting we can use `!=` to simplify:

```
if (this.prop != null) // checks null and undefined
```

Because `null == undefined` but `null !== undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, just an early morning javascript confusion :-/