# How does CoffeeScript's existential operator work?

Tags: coffeescript, existential-operator

Coffeescript uses the existential operator to determine when a variable exists, and in the [coffeescript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) it shows that `something?` would compile to `something !== undefined && something !== null` however I noticed that my version of coffeescript was only compiling this to `something !== null` so I wrote a test to see how this would effect my code

```
taco = undefined 

if taco?
    console.log "fiesta!"
else 
    console.log "No taco!"
```

which compiled to

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function() {
  var taco;

  taco = void 0;

  if (taco != null) {
    console.log("fiesta!");
  } else {
    console.log("No taco!");
  }

}).call(this);
```

and outputted the somewhat unexpected `No taco!` so my question is two fold. Why does coffeescript no longer check for the value being `undefined` and why is this suficiant?

Comment: Not an exact question duplicate, but the answer is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990117/existential-operator-and-object-properties :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The documentation says this about `?`:

> CoffeeScript's existential operator `?` returns true unless a variable is **null** or **undefined**, which makes it analogous to Ruby's `nil?`

so of course this will say "No taco!":

```
taco = undefined 
if taco?
    console.log "fiesta!"
else 
    console.log "No taco!"
```

Your `taco` is explicitly `undefined` so `taco?` is false.

CoffeeScript implicitly declares variables so the JavaScript form of `?` is context dependent. For example, if you just say only this:

```
if taco?
    console.log "fiesta!"
else 
    console.log "No taco!"
```

you'll see that `taco?` becomes `typeof taco !== "undefined" && taco !== null`. You still see the "is it `null`" check (in a tighter form) but there's also the "is there a `var taco`" check with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof); note that the `typeof taco` test also checks for `taco = undefined` so a stricter `!==` test can be used to see if `taco` is `null`.

You say this:

> I noticed that my version of coffeescript was only compiling this to `something !== null`

but that's not what it is doing, it is actually compiling to `something != null`; note the use of "sloppy" type converting inequality (`!=`) versus the strict inequality (`!==`) that you claim is there. The difference between `!=` and `!==` is important here [since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> - Null and Undefined Types are `==` (but not `===`)

So if you know that variable `v` has been declared (i.e. there is `var v` somewhere) then `v != null` is sufficient to check that `v` is neither `null` nor `undefined`. However, if you do not know that `v` has been declared, then you need a `typeof` check to avoid a ReferenceError when you try to compare an undeclared variable with `null`. Consider this JavaScript:

```
if(taco != null) {
    console.log("fiesta!");
} else {
    console.log("No taco!");
}
```

That will throw a ReferenceError in your face since `taco` does not exist. This:

```
if(typeof taco !== "undefined" && taco !== null)
    console.log("fiesta!");
} else {
    console.log("No taco!");
}
```

on the other hand is fine since the `typeof` check guards against trying to access something that hasn't been declared. I don't think you can construct the first one in CoffeeScript without embedding JavaScript using backticks.

Comment: Great answer.  I wish that the question was labeled, "In CoffeeScript, how does the existential operator work?" so your answer were easier to find.  Instead I have to favorite the question so I can find this again.