# In CoffeeScript, what is the existential operator for and how do you use it?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

I see all sorts of questions about the existential operator on SO, but none of them ask the fundamental question of "what is it for" and "how do you use it?" so I thought I'd ask this here.

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17254515/61624) would probably suffice as an answer to this question, but the problem is the question title doesn't suggest that.  As a result, it's very hard to find this question by a google search.  So, my intention here is to make it easier to learn what this operator does from a google search.

BTW, I am aware of the section in the [The Little Book on CoffeeScript](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/02_syntax.html) titled "Aliases & the Existential Operator", but for some reason I don't like its explanation.  It doesn't make me feel like "I get it".

Comment: Why didn't you just change the title of the original question, as others have suggested?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't know I could do that since I didn't write it.  I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existential operator provides a more concise and expressive way to handle `null` and `undefined` properties.

Instead of

```
if (user && user.url && user.url.indexOf('foo'))
```

you can do

```
if user?.url?.indexOf 'foo'
```

Instead of

```
if (baker.bakeBread) { baker.bakeBread()}
```

you can do coffeescript

```
baker.bakeBread?()
```

Comment: OK great answer.  Even more concise and helpful than what I linked to.