# JavaScript: if var? where var is no bool

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coffeescript, boolean

I am not understanding some piece of code of the videojs player:

```
if currentSrc?
    $(".video-js").replaceWith(
      "<div class='unsupported'><a href='#{currentSrc}'>Download</a></div>")
```

As I understand it, currentSrc has to be a bool to be checked for true or false in the if statement, but later integrated in the link it is a string.
Does `if var?` check the var just for existence? Wouldn't that be an incorrect way to check it in JS?

Comment: In case of a string it will use the length of the string to determine true/false. a length of 0 being false and everything else being true. you can try it with this: alert(("false" ? 'true' : "false"))

Comment: I don't think this is a valid JS

Comment: *currentSrc has to be a bool*, not neccarily JS will coerce the value into a bool. JS is not a typed language and will alter types based on usage

Comment: @Liam this code is along the lines of `if a ? 1`, which gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…)`

Comment: hmm, I dind't notice the `?`..does look a little odd.

Comment: It's [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#operators)!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [**How does CoffeeScript's existential operator work?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17253772/479863)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> currentSrc has to be a bool to be checked for true or false in the if statement

Incorrect. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. A string of non-zero length (which any URL will be) will be a true value.

```js
var foo = "";
var bar = "some value";

if (foo) { console.log(foo); } else { console.log("foo is false"); }
if (bar) { console.log(bar); } else { console.log("bar is false"); }
```

Comment: So `ìf var?` is true, when var is a non-empty string and `if var` is true, when var is a string with content "true", do I get this right?

Comment: Just to add clarity: this is due to the Truthy concept in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy - when a string is evaluated as a boolean it will be true when it has non-zero length and false when it has 0 length.

Comment: To correct myself: `if var?` is true when var is a non-zero length string and `if var` is true when var is a boolean with value true.

Comment: But the question is CoffeeScript so `if(x)` and `if(x?)` are very different things.

Answer (score -1):

A nice easy way to see how javascript transforms booleans, is to use a double negation `!!`.

Not sure the downvote, but personally I find this technique usefull, mainly because I have Chrome open, if I'm unsure of a boolean evaluation, I just open the console and type what I'm checking.. eg.  type `!!-1` , in this case it would return `true`, some other languages might see this as `false`

eg.

```js
console.log( "''", !!'' );  //false
console.log( "hello2", !!'hello' );  //true
console.log( "0", !!0 );  //false
console.log( "'0'", !!'0' );  //true
console.log( "1", !!1 ); //true
console.log( "true", !!true ); //true
console.log( "null", !!null ); //false
console.log( "undefined", !!undefined ); //false
```